# Select web.config or app.config Connection String based on Machine Name

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, app-config

This question, loosely relates to [Choose settings based on machine name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488227/choose-settings-based-on-machine-name) asked previously, however I have a much more specific use for it, which I am hoping is baked into .Net by default.

I am one of several people in a small team writing DotNet desktop and web applications. We use git as the source repository, and it becomes tiresome to have to constantly change the .config file connection strings for each of the development environments.

I know there are several ways to overcome this problem; which range from not storing the .config files in the repo in the first place (and using .gitignore), through to writing code to parse the configuration file manually adding prefixes etc as is suggested in the other question.

However, this seems both overly simplistic and tedious; as in a production environment there may be lots of legitimate reasons to store multiple connection strings in the config file  - such as having several servers - that makes me think there has to be an easier way to do it.

So my question is this: ***Is there a way in the DotNet .config files to have multiple connection strings that the framework 'automatically' knows which one to load based on a property, such as the environment or machine name?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question for clarity: Is there something about [config transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.100).aspx) that do not meet this requirement? Setup the active solution configuration based on the build configuration manager settings (environment) and replace the nodes as needed. We do this all the time for web, console, and service projects. Perfectly suited for web (built-in) and others (with some minor post build tweaking).

Comment: Wow, just wow. Trust Microsoft to have such an overly engineered way of doing something simple.  That article looks to be exactly what I'm looking for, but man it gave me a headache and put me to sleep!  I was hoping for something extremely trivial, but I'll try to gather the strength and look into this in more detail.

Comment: Local (MS) SQL instances can often be referred to with a simple . character (i.e. ".\SQLEXPRESS"), which could be useful and not require any magic post-build transformations. Otherwise you'll have to do some legwork, sorry.

Comment: Yeah thats prolly the best suggestion for now - that will get me out of trouble for the current project...thanks.